# Add IP Address Authentication to Windows Azure AD or SharePoint Online?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

We need IP Address Authentication for a SharePoint Online Website: only users from specific IP ranges should be (automatically) authenticated and permitted to enter the page. This is offered by several Identity Management providers but I do not see anything permitting such an implementation (C# etc.) or configuration with WAAD or SharePoint Online. Am I missing something.

The alternative would be to add an additional Identity Provider that provides this capability and then federate it via SAML/WSFed with WAAD.

Other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your need, and I have heard this from other customers too. But as of today, there is no option to whitelist IP address for authentication. The only option available for customers today is to Whitelist IP addresses for MFA (i.e. do not enforce MFA when user is logging in from whitelisted IP address).

Funny enough, this request is not even on the Feature requests lists: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory - if you put it there, you got my 3 votes and a chance for implementation.